# Correction for sampling from infinite population?

Tags: sampling, simulation, finite-population

I am currently creating a procedure to simulate the generation of data from an unknown, finite population (size $N$).

Let's say data generation for a sample of $n = 100$ is done by drawing from a standard normal distribution:

```
X <- rnorm(n = 100)
```

So even though the actual population is finite, simulated data is generated from an infinite population.

Moreover, the final dataset contains a weight ($W$) column, where $W = N / n$. So the final output in this example would be something like

```
> data.frame(X, W)
              X  W
1    0.51480970 10
2    1.34291139 10
3   -0.03628744 10
4    0.37418631 10
5    0.11057103 10
6    0.22536402 10
```

I understand that If I were sampling from a finite distribution without replacement, a finite population correction (FPC) factor might be in order depending on how small those weights are. Thus, **I am wondering what the consequences for generating data in the demonstrated setup are. Do the data need to be corrected? Are there any other downsides?** Since FPC is used to "fix" the probability differences created by sampling without replacement and infinite populations can be seen as samples with replacement I feel like my procedure is OK, but I might be missing something and would love to hear what the community has to say.

**Edit:** as an example, let's say the estimator to be calculated is the sample mean and the target or inference is the actual population.

Comment: The question of using correction factors can be answered only by knowing (1) what estimator you are using and (2) whether the target of inference is this "actual population" or the process used to simulate the data.  Could you include that information within your question?

Comment: @whuber sorry for the late reply. I've edited the question to address your comments.